# Displaying the g meta using script and div to display in the head tag of another page

Tags: javascript, php, html

Well, since yesterday I've been trying, today the idea occurred to me to create a div in ver.php and call it via script in index.php in the  tag, but I can't display the data inside the head just load the script, but it doesn't insert the div data in the head tag of index.php the div is functional and retrieves the data I need, but I'm in this situation, because I can't get the script to run and include the div data in the < head > tag in index .php?

thanks in advance.
any help is welcome.

Script in index.php where it should load the div data:
[image]

Div Header being displayed
[image]

---

div created in ver.php file

```
<div id="header">
 
  <link rel="canonical" href="<?= URL . $dados['post']-> url?>">                
            <meta property="og:url" content="<?= URL . $dados['post']-> url?>" /> 
             <meta property="og:image" content="<?= URL.'/uploads/imagens/'.$dados['post']->capa ?>" />
            
<link rel="image_src" type="image/gif" href="<?= URL.'/uploads/imagens/'.$dados['post']->capa ?>">
</div>
```

---

public/Index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include './../app/phperror.php';
include './../app/configuracao.php';
include './../app/autoload.php';
 
error_reporting (0);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
    <script> 
 $(function(){
  $("#header").load("../app/Views/posts/ver.php"); 
  
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this. however i'm not sure if it will work during facebook url inspection. but follow the content.

```
<script>
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML += '<link rel="canonical" href="<?= URL . $dados['post']-> url?>">';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML += '<meta property="og:url" content="<?= URL . $dados['post']-> url?>">';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML += '<meta property="og:image" content="<?= URL.'/uploads/imagens/'.$dados['post']->capa ?>">';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML += '<link rel="image_src" type="image/gif" href="<?= URL.'/uploads/imagens/'.$dados['post']->capa ?>">';
 
 
console.log(meta);
 </script>
```